# Loop Outputs as Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, output-formatting, linear-algebra, vector

```
\[GothicCapitalR] = {{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 
 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}};
i = 1;
j = 1;
det = 1;
a = Subsets[Range[6], {3}];
v = {x, y, z};
k = \[GothicCapitalR].v;
r = k[[a[[i]]]];
Det[r];
While[i < 21,
 r = k[[a[[i]]]];
 det = Factor[Det[r]];
 Print[det]; i++]


-(x+y+z) (x^2-x y+y^2-x z-y z+z^2)
(x-y) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-z) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-y) (x-z) (x+y+z)
(x-z) (y-z) (x+y+z)
(x-y) (x-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-y) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-z) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-y) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-y) (x-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-y) (x-z) (x+y+z)
(x-y) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-z) (y-z) (x+y+z)
(x-y) (y-z) (x+y+z)
(x-y) (x-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-z) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x-y) (x-z) (x+y+z)
(x-z) (y-z) (x+y+z)
(x-y) (y-z) (x+y+z)
-(x+y+z) (x^2-x y+y^2-x z-y z+z^2)
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get the output of this loop to be a list of polynomials so that I can use the `PolynomialLCM` function on it? I will be adapting this loop to larger dimensions and will need to be able to have Mathematica perform this calculation for me.

Comment: Do you mean so it isn't a string?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `While[i<21,...]`, use `Table[...,{i,20}]`. The ... part can be reduced to

```
r = k[[a[[i]]]];
Factor[Det[r]]
```

To find the `PolynomialLCM`, simply replace the head ( `List`) of the table with `PolynomialLCM` using `Apply`, or `@@` for short:

```
PolynomialLCM @@ Table[...,{i,20}]
```

Comment: This is indeed a much tighter means to create the same list, Is there a way to get the LCM of this output without selecting them manually?

Comment: Yes, see my edited post. You should probably read the doc's on `Apply`, `Map` and `Table`, as these are some of the cornerstones in _Mathematica_ ;)

Answer (score 2):

Replace the Print[det] in the print with:

```
Paste[det]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\[GothicCapitalR] = {{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 
 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}};
i = 1;
j = 1;
det = 1;
a = Subsets[Range[6], {3}];
v = {x, y, z};
k = \[GothicCapitalR].v;
PolynomialLCM @@ Table[Factor[Det[k[[a[[i]]]]]], {i, 1, 20}]
```